# trying to make some divs fadeOut and then be removed

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm trying to make some divs fadeOut and then be removed.

```
$("article.articles .thumb a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected");
    $("article.post").not(".selected").fadeOut(500).delay(1500).remove();
    $('#stream').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

But the divs are removed right away without fading.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `delay()` works on the animation queue, `remove()`is not in that queue, so there's no effect. The posted answers should work for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `fadeOut()` callback function which is executed after fade effect is complete.

> .fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )

```
$("article.post").not(".selected").fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).remove();
})
```

or:

```
$("article.post").not(".selected").fadeOut(500).delay(2000).queue(function(){
   $(this).remove()
})
```

Comment: @Gab can you post the HTML part?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("article.articles .thumb a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected");
    $("article.post").not(".selected").fadeOut(500, function(){
    setTimeout(function(item){ 
      jQuery(item).remove(); }, 1500, $(this));
});
    $('#stream').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the div to fade out before removing it. You need to create a callback function and call remove inside it.

Use this Snippet-

```
   $("article.post").not(".selected").fadeOut(500, function(){
                            $("article.post").not(".selected").remove();
                        });
```